# Dynamically setting min value on textfield using Jquery Validate plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I'm trying to have a dynamically updated min value on one field, depending on input from other fields.  Heres my code in short:

```
$("#new_project").live("click", function() {

    switch($('input:radio[name=quality-level]:checked').val()){
        case 'average' : ppw = .006;
        case 'below-average' : ppw =.004;
        case 'good' : ppw = .008;
        case 'very-good' : ppw = .016;
    }

    if ($('#minimum-word-length').val() && $('input:radio[name=quality-level]:checked').val())
    {
        min_price = $('#minimum-word-length').val() * ppw;

    }

    $("#new_project, .edit_project").validate({
    rules: {
    ...
    "price-per-article": {required: true, number: true,  min:min_price},
    ...
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) { }


    });

});
```

Min price is set correctly, and updates correctly.  That said, for whatever reason, the min value rule doesnt update which i think is because the validate code is only loaded on document load.  So I guess is there a way to reload the rules so that the min value changes when then the two necessary fields are filled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is you're setting up the validate object with the price-per-article on initial load.  I'm not familiar with the validate plug-in, but in general, if your properties change for an object real time, you'll want to use a callback function for that property as opposed to setting it's data on load.

So for the price-per-article entry it'd probably look like:

```
"price-per-article": {
  required: true,
  number: true,
  min: function () { return $('#minimum-word-length').val() * ppw; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having a fixed value for the validation for price-per-article, change it to an anonymous function:

```
"price-per-article": {
    required: true,
    number: true,
    min: function() { return min_price; }
}
```

This way the value of min_price is checked every time validation is called.

Answer (score 0):

This example gets min year & max year is derived from min:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function getMinYear() {
        var d = new Date();
        var y = parseInt(d.getFullYear());

        console.log("Min: " + y);
        return y;
    }

    $("#frmAddCard").validate({
        rules : {
            year : {
                required : true,
                number: true,
                min: getMinYear(),
                max: getMinYear() + 10
            }
        },
        messages : {                
            year : {
                required : "Expiration Date: Please enter valid year (e.g. 2016)",
                number : "Expiration Date: Please enter valid year (e.g. 2016)",
                min : function (elem) {
                    var y = getMinYear();

                    return "Min: Please enter the value between " + y.toString() + " and " + (y + 10).toString();
                },
                max : function (elem) {
                    var y = getMinYear() + 10;

                    return "Max: Please enter the value between " + y.toString() + " and " + (y + 10).toString();
                }
            }
        },
        submitHandler : function (form) {
        },
        invalidHandler : function (event, validator) {              
        }
    });
});
```